# Deleted contacts from removed dual-SIM still visible in WhatsApp

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger, sim-card, dual-sim

Earlier I had 2 SIM cards and contacts from both contacts were visible in my WhatsApp.

But after removing one of my SIM cards, the contacts from both 2 SIM contacts are still visible in WhatsApp (which are not visible in my address book, only in WhatsApp).

Please tell me, how to delete them.